# Smoothing DEM using GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, shaded-relief

I have a SRTM DEM and I want to create a shaded relief from it. I created the shaded relief in GRASS and the result is very nice, but a little rough because the area is near flat and the DEM is 90m in resolution.

What I want is to make the DEM smoother in order to generate a smooth shaded relief. Is there an algorithm or interpolation method to do that?

Here is the shaded relief to get an idea, I want to flatten these small bumps:

[image]

Comment: See also : [How do I install mdenoise in GRASS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73379/)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

How about John Stevenson's `r.denoise`, from the [GRASS AddOns wiki](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_AddOns#r.denoise):

> [r.denoise](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.denoise) denoises (smooths/despeckles) topographic data, particular
>   DEMs derived from radar data (including SRTM), using [Xianfang Sun's
>   denoising algorithm](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Page342.htm). It is designed to preserve sharp edges and to
>   denoise with minimal changes to the original data.

[image: mdenoise]

I read further from [this website](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/neil.mitchell/mdenoise/) (that I also give credit for the above animation) that a more generic method would be to use an Esri ASCII Grid file. The location of `mdenoise` (downloaded from [Sun's website](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Page342.htm)) needs to be in your PATH variable (e.g., Windows users: drop `MDenoise.exe` in the `bin` folder with your OSGeo4w or FWTools install). Then, for example, you can use the following shell command to process the ASCII grid file:

```
# gdal_translate -of AAIGrid my_dem.tif my_dem.asc      # convert to .asc
mdenoise -i my_dem.asc -n 5 -t 0.99 -o my_dem_DN.asc    # denoise
# gdal_translate -of GTiff my_dem_DN.asc my_dem_DN.tif  # convert back to .tif
```

Denoise is under GNU license, see [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.denoise/r.denoise)

Comment: Any python / gdal portage ?

Comment: You can always run any command from Python.

Comment: I mean a python equivalent which doesn't need R.

Comment: This doesn't require R. From Python, use `os.system('mdenoise ...')` to run the executable.

Comment: To clarify: The r. here stands for raster. The command is from GRASS GIS, not from R.

Answer (score 12):

Tom Patterson, the lead cartographer at the U.S. National Parks Service has [some excellent tutorials](http://www.shadedrelief.com/) on working with DEM data to make beautiful shaded reliefs. Part of his workflow involves using [Natural Scene Designer](http://www.naturalgfx.com/) and Adobe Photoshop.

For my own workflow I like to use GDAL to resample the size of the DEM before rendering a shaded relief. This often helps with reducing the amount of detail and noise, not to mention file size. I have a [tutorial on Github](https://github.com/clhenrick/gdal_hillshade_tutorial#resampling-terrain-data) that demonstrates how to do this.

Basically the process is to specify a new width and/or height (in pixels) for an output DEM that is smaller than the original file size. For example doing:

```
gdalwarp -ts 3000 0 -r bilinear kings_canyon_2228.tif kings_canyon_2228_rs.tif
```

Will reduce the width of the DEM to 3000 pixels from the original width of 3800 pixels. Setting the height to 0 will let GDAL determine the best height of the new file based on the original's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 8):

I used GIMP plugin wavelet noise reduction tool and I get good results and fast:

[GIMP Plugin Wavelet noise reduction](http://registry.gimp.org/node/4235/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I smoothed my raster (hillshade) however the file (tiff) has lost spatial reference. So, when I put it into my qgis project the one didn't overlay correctly with other layers. Have happened this with you?

Comment: There are ways to reinject the geolocation.

Comment: Yes, in QGIS export the hillshade in raster menu, and expor to to PNG.

Answer (score 6):

You could run a simple filter on the DEM - say, a 5x5 moving window average filter.

Answer (score 3):

In ArcMap I like to use the Spatial Analyst>focal statistics tool to smooth out lidar prior to making contours...this might also help in your hillshading case.  It's a similar function to the above post I believe.

Comment: oops, just read the GRASS part...well I'm sure there is a similar operation...