# How do I install mdenoise in GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

How do I install mdenoise in GRASS 6.4.3?  I've already successfully installed r.denoise, and have downloaded mdenoise from wget http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Doc/mdsource.zip. How do I proceed now?

Comment: Did you noticed and gave a try to this [grass-addons/r.denoise](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.denoise)

Answer (score 1):

*mdenoise* seems to be a standalone command and cannot installed "in GRASS". You still can combine it with GRASS commands, of course.

Compile it on unix platforms with

```
g++ -o mdenoise mdenoise.cpp triangle.c
```

as described in the README file.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that, and have read the readme file but am not familiar with the terminology used.