# Creating transparent hillshade?

Tags: gdal, dem, gdal-translate, hillshade, gdal-calc

I get elegant transparent hillshades via a combination `gdal` and `convert`. Compare to grey-based hillshade commonly used, such transparent hillshades are very cool because they can be placed between the map background and other upper layers (roads, buiding) to provide a 3D feels whatever the background's type and color.

#### **How it works**

**The trick:** Starting with a grey scale hillshade produced by `gdal hillshade`, the trick is to take the grey channel's values, invert each value, and flow this result into a new opacity channel. Black pixel [0,0,0] become [0,0,0,255] (opacity=255), grey pixel [120,120,120] get lower becoming  [120,120,120,135] (opacity=135, aka 255-120), white pixel [255,255,255] become transparent [255,255,255,0] (opacity=0, aka 255-255) and so on. Hills' shades are **opaque and black**, plains progressively become **(white) transparent**. Conceptually, the pixel's band equation is something such :

```
alpha_value([0])    = 255-0 = 255;   // black pixels get full opacity
alpha_value([Grey]) = 255-Grey;
// grey pixels get 255-GreyValue opacity.
alpha_value([255])  = 255-255 = 0  // white pixels get null opacity !
```

For a laid back video on this approach, explained by a Photoshop designer, see [Adding Shaded Relief in Photoshop](https://youtu.be/LcL11S4Vgqk) (16mins).

#### **Question**

Taking an ETOPO or SRTM derived grey-based hillshade (`gdaldem hillshade crop_xl.tmp.tif shadedrelief.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges`, [file available to download here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Shadedrelief.tmp.tif)) as input...

**...How to do the trick cited upper via gdal or an other non GIS-destructive way on such .tif files ?**

Note that I wish to keep GIS properties (geolocalisation).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Depending on how the referencing data is stored in the tiff it may be as easy as renaming the world file associated with the tiff.

Comment: @Steve: it's for .tif files generated from raster such SRTM or ETOPO after `gdaldem hillshade etopo_crop.tif shadedrelief.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges`

Comment: I think [`gdal_tranlate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with a combination of **-b *band***, **-mask *band***, **-expand *gray|rgb|rgba*** together witht the formula `opacity=-(px_grey_value)+255` may be the way to go, but I never touched bands and I'am still quite clueless.

Comment: added [grey-based hillshade to download](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Shadedrelief.tmp.tif)

Comment: have you tried gdal_edit.py to rewrite the coordinate, cell size and reference system ?

Comment: @radouxju: thanks for [gdal_edit](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html). Actually, your other answer will do the trick, as I want to avoid meta-data deletion or rewriting. :)

Comment: Excellent write-up. Thanks ! My only problem being the flat area out of gdal hillshade is 181 and not 221. I failed identifying where the difference was coming from...
With this 181 value, the proposed thereshold of is 180-220 not very suitable. I have to pick lower values but then I loose a little bit the 3D rendering. I thought trying the "white area" method that is described above. But failed understanding how "enlightening" should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96800)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### **Nutshell**

Each set of 3 images below should be read such as ***"grey (band) + opacity (band) = transparent result"***. You can test these processes within minutes via the associated [github hosted makefile](https://github.com/hugolpz/gdal_transparent_hillshades). Process **#3** is the one which I recommend, with a threshold between 170 (keeps strong shadows) and 220 (keeps all shadows). Process 3 provides the strongest shadows and **avoid** greying-whitening effect. Adapt the resulting layer's overall opacity as needed. The equations in `--calc="<equation>"` may be improved as needed as well, using `gdal_calc`.

For a laid back video on this approach, explained by a Photoshop designer, see [Adding Shaded Relief in Photoshop](https://youtu.be/LcL11S4Vgqk) (16mins).

#### **Background**

[`gdaldem hillshade`](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_hillshade) produces a one band grey scale file with pixels values range=[1-255], aka from the darkest shadows to the most enlighten pixel. For flat areas, px=221 (#DDDDDD). `NoDataValue` pixels get default nodatavalue `0`, also, the darkest black in input and in output is and should be `1`.  With no opacity band defined, **opacity is 100%**.

```
gdaldem hillshade input.tif hillshade.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
```

[image: hillshade.tmp.tif]

We want to define and control a 2nd opacity band !

#### **Objectives**

We want **one greyscale band** `-b 1`, it's the hillshade. Out of gdal, it's a grey band with continuous range such as px=[1-255]. We can crop out non-relevant areas (#2), or blacken it to px=1 and rely on the opacity band (#3).

We want **one opacity band** `-b 2`, generally the invert of the hillshade or a related function of that. We can crop out non-relevant areas (#2). It must be a continuous range of opacities such px=[1-255], otherwhise there is no elegance.

[`gdal_calc`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) can be use to both do math on pixels from input files A,B,C... and check boolean values such as `A<220`, which returns 1 (true) or 0 (false). This allow conditional calculus. If the condition is false, the related part of the equation is nullified.

#### **1. Grey hillshade made transparent**

The following provides a very good two-bands results with the standard `gdal hillshade` greys and whiter areas made increasingly transparent :

```
# hillshade px=A, opacity is its invert: px=255-A
gdal_calc.py -A ./hillshade.tmp.tif  --outfile=./opacity.tif --calc="255-A"
# assigns to relevant bands -b 1 and -b 2
gdalbuildvrt -separate ./final.vrt ./hillshade.tmp.tif ./opacity.tif
```

[image: hillshade.tmp.tif]
[image: #1, opacity.tif]
[image: #1, final.tif]

#### **2. Optimization via pseudo-crop (-b 1 & -b 2)**

2/3 of the pixels on `-b 1` (greyscale) become invisible to bare eyes when the opacity `-b 2` is added, yet, these pixels keeps various whiter `-b 1` and low opacity `-b 2` values. They can be made all white transparent `[255,1]` pixels, allowing a better compression rate:

```
# filter the color band, keep greyness of relevant shadows below limit
gdal_calc.py -A ./hillshade.tmp.tif  --outfile=./color_crop.tmp.tif \
    --calc="255*(A>220) +      A*(A<=220)"
# filter the opacity band, keep opacity of relevant shadows below limit
gdal_calc.py -A ./hillshade.tmp.tif  --outfile=./opacity_crop.tmp.tif \
    --calc="  1*(A>220) +(256-A)*(A<=220)"
# gdalbuildvrt -separate ./final.vrt ./color_crop.tmp.tif ./opacity_crop.tmp.tif
# gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -co ALPHA=YES ./final.vrt ./final_crop.tif
```

[image: #2, color.tif (cropped)]
[image: #2, opacity.tif (cropped)]
[image: #2, final_crop.tif]

#### **3. Further -b 1 optimization (crop + blacken)**

Since we have an progressive opacity band `-b 2` to rely on, we could make `-b 1` pixels either white px=255 via `255*(A>220)`, or black px=1 via `1*(A>220)`.

```
gdal_calc.py -A ./hillshade.tmp.tif  --outfile=./color.tmp.tif \
   --calc="255*(A>220) + 1*(A<=220)"
# gdal_calc.py -A ./hillshade.tmp.tif  --outfile=./opacity_crop.tmp.tif \
#  --calc="  1*(A>220) +(256-A)*(A<=220)".
# gdalbuildvrt -separate ./final.vrt ./color.tmp.tif ./opacity_crop.tif
# gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -co ALPHA=YES ./final.vrt ./final.tif
```

[image: #3, color.tif]
[image: #2, opacity.tif (cropped)]
[image: #3, final.tif]

This result shows **stronger shadows**.

#### **Result**

Create a transparent hillshade has for immediate objective to remove the plain's former grey areas and associated **unwanted but ubiquitous** greying-fading effect. The wished byproduct is an increased control over the final visual product. The process described remove most grey and all white pixels. The colorful background plain image will keep its chosen colors when overlayed by the transparent-to-black hillshades, **only** the shadowed areas will be darkened. Comparison of process #2 (left) and #3 (right) below.

Overview "Before vs After" :

[image: Comparison of process #2 (left) and #3 (right), general view.]

Zoom, please notice the shadows (before vs after) :

[image: Comparison of process #2 (left) and #3 (right), details view.]

#### **Further optimizations**

**White areas**: One may also wish to keep the most enlightened areas to increase the 3D feels. It would literally be the symmetric of this current approach with minor threshold changes, then a merge of both outputs via gdal_calc. The plain would be 100% transparent, the darkest shadows and lightest enlighten areas opaque.

**Smoothing:** The input hillshade may be pre-smoothed to get a better end result, see [Smoothing DEM using GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12833/)

**Composite hillshade** ([How to create composite hillshade?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146296/)).

**Bumped hillshade** is interesting as well ([description](http://www.shadedrelief.com/bumping/bumping.html))

#### **Notes**

- The **flat area threshold** in `gdal hillshade` output is px=221 (#DDDDDD = [221,221,221]), marking flat areas. Also, hillshade's px=221 divides the images between in-shadow slopes (A<221) and in-light slopes (A>221) pixels.
- A **processing threshold** at px=[170-220] as proven good, it keeps near 100% of the eyes-noticeable shadows, which themselves barely stand for 15-35% of the relief area.
- **Filesize > Compression:** final.tif out of #1, #2, #3 is ~1.3MB without compression,  then ~0.3-0.16MB after compression, 80% saving !
- **Filesize > cropping:** From .326KB in #1, crop color & opacity (#2) get to 310kb, blacken color (#3) get to 160kb. Cropping effect on filesize is between 5~50% reduction with threshold at px=220 and my input.

Comment: Encouraging +1 welcome.

Comment: While you did have to answer yourself this thread is an excellent tutorial touching on a lot of questions regarding hillshading. Well done!

Comment: Your tutorial is just work. Great work. Could you please consider answer my question => [***here***](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/293991)? Is it possible to create .ovr for this kind of GeoTIFF, grayscale with alpha band?

Comment: Hello @sandthorn, despite my love for it I'am not in this field anymore. The cost to find the answer will likely be higher for me-2018 than for you-2018. Hope my stuff point to the right direction for your issue!

Comment: How to create hilshade in browser 
 https://observablehq.com/@sahilchinoy/hillshader

Answer (score 9):

Another way to get the same result of a non-grey canvas more suitable for combining with other layers is the 'combined' option in gdaldem.

It performs a slope and hill shade and combines the two in one operation. Areas of 0 slope are white. Areas of 90 degree slope are black for the slope shade, with some illumination added by the hillshade layer.

`gdaldem hillshade -combined -compute_edges infile outfile.tif`

Then use a multiply layer compositing mode to 'drape' this over other layers.

Standard/Combined hillshading

[image: Standard Hillshading]

Combined shading multiplied with OSM base layer (opacity around 50%)
[image: Combined shading multiplied with OSM base layer]

Comment: Is there a way to combine the OSM layer with the hillshad layer with gdal?

Answer (score 3):

#### **`gdal` + `convert` based workflow**

There is a `gdal` + `convert` solution which gives good visual results. The trouble with this solution is that **`convert` destroys geographic informations** which you then have to restore. It increase the number of action to run.

```
# Basic crop
gdal_translate -projwin 67 35.92 99 5 ../data/noaa/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop_xl.tmp.tif
# Grey-based hillshade
gdaldem hillshade crop_xl.tmp.tif shadedrelief.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
# create a transparent hillshade:
convert shadedrelief.tmp.tif -fuzz 7% -fill "#FFFFFF" -opaque "#DDDDDD"  whited.jpg # makes all grey values white to lighten the filesize
convert whited.jpg -alpha copy -channel alpha -negate +channel trans.png # <=== TRICK HERE.
# Restore georeferencing & reproject            
gdal_translate -a_ullr 67 35.92 99 5 trans.png trans.tmp.gis.tif
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs ESPG:3857 ./trans.tmp.gis.tif ./trans_reproj.tmp.gis.tif
# Compress from 11MB to 2MB:
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -co ALPHA=YES ./trans_reproj.tmp.gis.tif ./trans.gis.tif
```

For command 4 explanation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23018544/1974961