# Add hillshade to naip imagery

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, hillshade, naip

I've been searching for quite a while now. Is there a way to merge a hillshade image with an aerial image with gdal? 
I'm just trying to create a hillshaded aerial image.

Comment: Are you trying to overlay the aerial image with a [transparent hillshade](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144535/how-to-create-transparent-hillshade) or what do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: I want to lay the hillshade on top of an aerial image and save than as one file using gdal. I have found numerous examples of creating the transparent hillshaded image but I can't seem to find the step where the hillshade actually gets combined with another image.

Comment: In that case: Have you tried [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)? As per [this ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3669) it should now be able to merge GeoTiffs with transparent Alpha channels.

Comment: Ideally, you will want to make the aerial imagery transparent and overlay it on the hillshade and not the other way around. Also, if you are comfortable with C++ [this repo](http://khafen74.github.io/raster2png) has a method to overlay two PNG images

Comment: What's the reason for overlaying g the image over the hillshade instead of the other way?