# QGIS conversion of USGS GeoTIFF to contours leaves strange artifacts at border of tiles?

Tags: qgis, gdal, contour, gdal-contour

I downloaded several USGS GeoTIFFs from the USGS Earth Explorer site (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).  These were then converted to contours using the qgis toolbox (GDAL -> Raster Extraction -> Contour).  The command was of the form:

```
gdal_contour -b 1 -a ELEV -i 5.0 -f "ESRI Shapefile" n33_w086_1arc_v3.tif n33_w086_1arc_v3.shp
```

At the boundaries of my tiles, there is a slight overlap which leaves a "ladder" effect:

[image: contours extend past tile boundary]

If I had to guess, these are artifacts resulting from GDAL hitting the edge of the GeoTIFF while processing a contour line.  These are very distracting visually.  How can they be trimmed or removed?

Comment: First: get more DEM data outside your focus area than you need, you can trim off the contours outside your AOI later. Second: Merge your GeoTIFF into one file, that way there won't be  internal edges. Third: smooth the DEM https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12833/smoothing-dem-using-grass then make your contours. This assumes you're only dealing with a relatively small area, for a larger area you'll hit the 2 GiB shapefile size limit depending on the ruggedness of the terrain and the contour interval.

Comment: Excellent advice. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Jeff W, please answer your own question expanding on my previous comment illuminating *how* you performed each of the tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the advice of Michael Stimson (see the response to the original question), this was quite easy.

First, add your GeoTIFF tiles:

[image]

Open the "Processing Toolbox", and access GDAL-> Raster Miscellaneous -> Merge:

[image]

Select the GeoTIFF tiles you want to merge:

[image]

A new "Merged" layer is added to your Layers panel.  Note that the tiles are normalized and appear cohesive:

[image]

Back in the Processing Toolbox, select GDAL -> Raster Extraction -> Contour:
[image]

Select your merged layer, adjust the settings as required, and press "Run":

[image]

Done!